# Haskell: binary search tree with a list

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree

I am trying to build a binary search tree, but it doesn't work as expected. For example, `treeListInsert [7,12,6,4,8]` gives me `Node 8 (Node 4 Nil (Node 6 Nil (Node 7 Nil Nil))) (Node 12 Nil Nil)`, which is wrong. Is there anything I did wrong? Thanks.

```
-- the tree structure should be
--       7
--      / \
--     6   12
--    /   /
--   4   8

-- but results
--       8
--      / \
--     4  12
--    / \
--   6   7

-- define the data structure
-- deriving Show to show Node in GHCI
data Tree a = Nil | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show

-- | treeInsert takes any number and
--   and return a Node
treeInsert :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
treeInsert x Nil = Node x Nil Nil -- build a Node
treeInsert x (Node root left right)
  | x == root = Node root left right -- avoid duplicate
  | x < root = Node root (treeInsert x left) right -- insert a node on a left
  | x > root = Node root left (treeInsert x right) -- insert a node on the right

-- | treeListInsert takes a list of numbers
--   and return a tree using treeInsert function
treeListInsert :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Tree a
treeListInsert [] = Nil -- empty list return Nil
treeListInsert (x:xs) = treeInsert x (treeListInsert xs) -- iterate through the list and insert x to tree repeatedly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your insert function is fine, but `treeListInsert` is equivalent to `foldr treeInsert Nil`. The base case is the end of the list, not the beginning. The tree you get looks wrong (4 has 6 as a left child), but that's because you drew it wrong, not because Haskell gave you a bad result.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between `foldr` and `foldl`.